# Disable volume-change sound

Tags: linux, audio, debian

I'm using Debian Wheezy with Gnome 3 and I'd like to disable the "bip" sound made when pressing the volume +/- keys. Audio programs that are running currently (I have no clue which program exactly controls this function) are:

gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor
gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
hd-audio0
pulseaudio

Comment: Look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/61878/how-can-i-disable-the-popping-sound-when-adjusting-the-volume/61880#61880

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Gnome3 so I can't check this, but according to [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=116649), you should be able to do the following:

1. Run `dconf-editor`
2. Navigate to `org -> gnome -> desktop -> sound -> event-sound` and deselect it. You *may* also want to deselect `input feedback sounds` if selected.

Comment: This doesn't work for Debian Jessie

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:
1. Run dconf-editor
2. Click the search icon on the top right and search "volume"
3. Disable